# Neo4j running behind proxy on IIS

Tags: iis, neo4j

What's required to setup Neo4j behind IIS proxy server?

I am running into the issue listed here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/112

Error message (Chrome console):

> displayed insecure content from =1363713541737">http://xyz:7474/db/data/?=1363713541737

`xyz` is the server name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the GitHub issue is still open, you can assume that this is not currently supported and no workaround has been supplied by Neo.

If you want to persist ahead, you will need to rewrite the content passing through the proxy.

Comment: We've implemented a webapi wrapper on top of neo4jclient (as a workaround), however, I would like to display webadmin embedded in my client/winform app this requires webadmin to work behind proxy in IIS (and it seems its not supported).